# Build Multiple apk from 1 project, for upload in playstore

Tags: java, android

I am working on a app for school in android studio using java
I want to generate multiple apk for school with their school name and logo, (about 50+ schools)
Is there any way to save time generating one by one
in future need to update all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read official guideline about [**`productFlavors`**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants).

> Creating product flavors is similar to creating build types: add them
>   to the productFlavors block in your build configuration and include
>   the settings you want. The product flavors support the same properties
>   as defaultConfig—this is because defaultConfig actually belongs to the
>   ProductFlavor class.

```
productFlavors {
        elvispresley {
            applicationId 'your_package_id'
            versionCode 1
            versionName '1.0'

        }
        whitneyhouston {
           applicationId 'your_package_id_2'
            versionCode 2
            versionName '2.0.1'

        }
        projectOne {
            applicationIdSuffix ".one"

        }
        projectTwo {
            applicationIdSuffix ".two"

        }
    }
```

Comment: I want different app logo and app name, Is this possible with productFlavors

Comment: @sanjaybhatt https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables